# How to track down the file a process is executed from on disk?

Tags: linux

I have a process being started on my server that appears to modify what ps/top sees, so I don't know the filename or the path of it since it's hiding it (it's a perl script). How can I track down where the file is on disk?

Comment: How do you know you have a hidden process ?

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: The process isn't hidden, it's just modifying what you see. I know this because I've tracked it down before (mostly due to luck) in /tmp and this is behaving the same. It's a virus being uploaded onto a shared hosting server via some client's insecure site. What ps sees is `/usr/sbin/httpd (perl5.8.8)` which doesn't exist on disk.

Comment: If it is a Perl script, surely you can read the Perl script and see what is going on

Comment: @fpmurphy: That's the issue of the topic, I can't locate it on disk this time as they've not used /tmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `/proc/<pid>/` there are various files which may help you find the culprit.

- `cmdline` is the command line used to start the process (including parameters). Unfortunately, this is apparently also changed if the process modifies its own command line.
- `cwd` is the working dir of the process, that might help as well
- `exe` points to the running executable (however, for Perl scripts that will be the Perl interpreter, so might not be so helpful)
- `status` contains various information. In particular, the parent process (Ppid) may be interesting; that will be the process that launched the script - might be helpful to find out who starts it.
- under `fd`, you'll find the list of files the process has currently opened (as symlinks); that should help figure out what it does

Comment: Janneb's answer is better - if the executable was found on the path, or run from an explicit relative path (since the cwd may not be what it was when it started). So really the exe link is the only clue here. In the case of a script running in an interpreter, to find the script, use lsof

Comment: @symcbean: Good points. Why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can check the /proc/[PID]/exe symlink, which points to the executable.